# Did anybody ever try to move a starship using the same trick Spock used in The Tholian Web?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

To escape the Tholian web, Spock and Scotty move the Enterprise through interphased space. The trick moves the starship 2.72 parsecs (8.87 lightyears).

Fast forward to 2:50 in this video snippet.

It's a neat trick. Does anybody ever try that again in any canon Star Trek story?

Comment: Kind of depends how you define interphased space, does it mean subspace, the warp 10 threshold (shudders), a transwarp tunnel, an underspace tube etc

Comment: Maybe this was used to develop the [phase-cloaking device](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Phasing_cloaking_device) used in the TNG episode [*The Pegasus.*](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Pegasus_(episode))

Comment: @JoeL. Could also be what the Romulans were doing in *The Next Phase* episode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Next_Phase

Answer (score 6):

What they meant by interphased space is never specified

However I believe the TV episodes and the movies are the only canon and I can say with some certainty that there is no other occurrence of a ship moving in that manner (by that manner I mean someone referring to it as interphased space and specifically trying to do it)

Ships have been pulled across the galaxy and ships have been pulled out of the galaxy, ships have traveled though time and ships have been cloaked, ships have been out of phase and ships have even been pulled into subspace there is really oh so many ways to move a ship.

Comment: Agreed. Given the length of time between TOS and TNG it's entirely possible that other technologies mentioned later are using the same technique under a different name, but as the audience we have no way of knowing for sure, if the relationship was never made explicit.